# Will a child process send SIGCHLD on abort()?

Tags: c, linux, fork, assert, sigchld

If an application does a `fork()` and the child dies with an `abort()` (due to failing an `assert()`), will the parent process receive a `SIGCHLD`?

If it's relevant this is on Debian 4 (gcc version 4.1.2).

Answer (score 4):

If you want to check the same,write a sample code which forks a child and the child calls abort() (To raise the sigabrt signal). Check its output on strace.(strace executable)

For the following code:

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<unistd.h>
 int main()
    {
    pid_t pid;
    if(pid=fork()<0)
            {
            fprintf(stderr,"Error in forking");
            }
    else if(pid==0)
            {
            /*The child*/
            abort();
            }
    else {
            waitpid(pid,(int *)0,0);
            }
    return 0;
    }
```

I get this output:

```
     --- SIGCHLD (Child exited) @ 0 (0) ---
     gettid()                                = 4226
     tgkill(4226, 4226, SIGABRT)             = 0
     --- SIGABRT (Aborted) @ 0 (0) ---
     +++ killed by SIGABRT +++
```

So the answer is yes, at least on Ubuntu distro.

Answer (score 1):

You would expect the parent to get a [SIGCHLD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGCHLD) any time a child terminates unless the child has separated itself off from the parent (IIRC using setsid() or setpgrp()).  The main reason for a child doing this is if the child is starting a daemon process.  See [Here](http://www.enderunix.org/documents/eng/daemon.php)  or [Here](http://cjh.polyplex.org/software/daemon.pdf) for a deeper treatment of daemon processes.

Comment: You still get a `SIGCHLD` when you separate, only it happens at the time the child separates, then the separated child has PID 1 as its parent so when that process dies, `SIGCHLD` is sent to process 1 (which more or less is the kernel)